# Delete item from the table if it's date is passed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, date

Hey I have a table that every row contains several data and one of them is the date , I am trying to write a code in php that will run on the table and delete every row that its date have been expired for example if the date today is 06/01/2017 than every item that its date is smaller than today should be deleted, the thing is I don't really have an idea on how to write this function so if someone can send me a tutorial or example of how should I do it that will be great.

Comment: You have to tell use at least the table names, field names and show what you have done so far. What you try is very basic mysql syntax.

Comment: Please try at least once, you will get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE FROM your_table WHERE your_date_column < NOW()` for what concerns the SQL query... Then simply use PDO to execute it

Your question actually is quite general, sounds like homework... Otherwise, posting some code attempts is appreciated as much as showing you did try / make some research beforehand. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a page that sets tomorrow's date and executes the mysql command:

```
$conn = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) { } 

$tomorrow = new DateTime('tomorrow');
$tomorrow->format('Y-m-d');

$sql = "DELETE FROM 'yourtable' WHERE Date < '{$tomorrow}'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query for delete past records

```
mysql> delete from your_table where date < curdate();
```